# Having quandl import issue

Tags: python-2.7, import, quandl

I'm struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong, since all I am doing is copying and pasting verbatim what I've been told works from [this source](https://www.quandl.com/docs/api?python#authenticating-your-requests).

Here is my code verbatim:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'REDACTED'
data = quandl.get("WIKI/FB")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
line 4, in <module>
    quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'REDACTED'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ApiConfig'
```

I am running Python2.7, so is there something I am missing? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13):

Just had the same problem.  Is your script named quandl.py?  When you run `import quandl`, and the package name is the same as the script, it tries to import itself and skips the package, even if it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running the api_config.py script that is actually in the quandl folder after the download. I actually ran all of them just in case another issue came up.